# Cannot set class for row when check box clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to set a css style to the row where checkbox is clicked but am unable to do so. The code is as follows. The code for checkbox click works fine for both the select all and individual check box. I want to get the `Request ID` for the selected rows and send them to the database via JSON object by post method to a php script.

Possibly the row is not getting selected.

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" name= "check_all" id="check_all"/></th>
                    <th>Request ID</th>
                    <th>Request Date</th>
                    <th>Leave Type</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

javascript

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
                data: msg,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'RequestID'},
                    { data: 'RequestID' },
                    { data: 'RequestDate' },
                    { data: 'LeaveType' },
                    { data: 'LeaveStart' },
                    { data: 'LeaveEnd' },
                    { data: 'Status' }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [ {
                     "targets": 0,
                      "searchable": false,
                      "data": "RequestID",
                      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name= "check_id[]" data-id="'+data+'" />';
                       }, 
                }]
            });

$("#check_all").click(function () {
        $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $(".checkBoxClass").change(function(){
        if (!$(this).prop("checked")){
            $("check_all").prop("checked",false);
            $('#mytable').row(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        }
            $('#mytable').row(this).addClass('row_selected');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

There are some issues with your code:

- You attach event handler directly but with jQuery DataTables only current page elements exist in DOM. Use delegated event handler instead.
- You need to access row node by using `$(this).closest('tr')`, not `$('#mytable').row(this)`
- Conditional statement was missing `else` part.

> **SOLUTION**

Use the code below to attach delegated event handler to all checkboxes.

```js
$("#mytable").on('change', '.checkBoxClass', function(){
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")){
        $("check_all").prop("checked", false);
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('row_selected');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('row_selected');
    }
});
```